# Can I check file existence using PMD rules?

Tags: java, validation, xpath, rules, pmd

I want to check if files existence using PMD rules, such as (gitignore, version, readme, . . . ) files.

What is the recommended way to do so?

I searched for the java rules and xpath rules in pmd but I couldn't find a clear article talking about this validations

Comment: I don't think, PMD does this, as it's a Java tool and doesn't know or care about the rest of your project setup. There are other linters that can help, e.g., markdown lint for checking your README.md.